# SQL Statement help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table where the date is being stored as a `varchar`, in the format `DD.MM.YYYY`.

I've created a stored proc that will query this table and return results based on Month and Year.

I'll have 2 input parameters being `MM` and `YYYY` - both coming in as strings.

What would the where clause be to get all items that match the month and year? I suspect I need to use a LIKE operator because it is a `varchar` field.

My SQL is rusty, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this(assuming @MM and @YYYY are your Input Parameters):

```
SELECT *
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
 WHERE <DATE_COLUMN> LIKE '[0-9][0-9].' + @MM + '.' + @YYYY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select * from table1 t
    where Month(Cast(t.DateCol as DateTime)) = Cast("1" as bigint)
    AND Year(Cast(t.DateCol as DateTime)) = Cast("2011" as bigint)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE field LIKE "%." + @month + "." + @year
```

However, the best way would be to create a new column with the correct data type, run a script to populate the correct datetime values in the new column, then ditch the varchar column and use MSSQLs built in ways of searching a datetime field. This will give you much faster lookups in the long run.

```
WHERE MONTH(field) = @month
      AND YEAR(field) = @year
```

Comment: Doh, I read "My SQL is rusty" as "My MySQL is rusty" in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE RIGHT(datecol,7)= @StringMM + "." + @StringYYYY
```